# Vue filtering table on nested data slower than basic CSS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, model-view-controller

I am moving old MVC code to Vue. I have one array A of objects (count > 60), and those objects contain a nested array B of objects.

array A = [{name: A, arrayB: B}, ...{}]

Based on search Text, I am filtering the items in the inner arrayB's.

I tried using this pattern https://codepen.io/AndrewThian/pen/QdeOVa, with a computed filtered list. However, this is running much slower than my vanilla JS, which loops over the whole list and sets visibility: hidden and height: 0. In particular, when I clear the search text, it seems to run really slowly adding all of the elements of the table back in.

filteredList() {
                    if (this.searchText == "") return this.categories;

```
                let filteredArray = new Array();
                this.A.forEach(outerElement=> {

                    let innerObj = new Object();
                    innerObj.Name= outerElement.Name;
                    innerObj.List= new Array();
                    outerElement.List.forEach(innerElement=> {
                        if (innerElement.Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText.toLowerCase())) {
                            //show = true;
                            innerObj.List.push(innerElement);
                        }
                    })
                    if (innerObj.List != undefined && innerObj.List.length > 0) filteredArray.push(innerObj);
                })
                return filteredArray;
            }
```

Is there a better way to approach efficiently filtering a nested table of data in Vue? V-show was also much slower than my vanilla version. all of the things I am seeing do not seem designed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming you’re using the filtered data in a **v-for** and generate DOM elements from data.

You should create a component that takes care of rendering a row from the table and send row data to it using props.

The reason why this is faster is that Vue re-renders the entire component when data changes, but when using components only the changed components are re-rendered, which leads to faster renders.

Do not forget to use **:key** on your **v-for**, otherwise Vue won’t be able to cache components. Also, index is not a good candidate for the key. Probably Name is a better candidate on your case.